# Comparing two columns of two separate CSV files and print corresponding column based on comparison

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv files such as:
file1:

```
12  
45  
67  
78
```

file2:

```
12  a  g  
45  k  l  
65  o  m  
89  p  r
```

I want to take 1st entry of 1st file and find it in 2nd file and print the corresponding 2 column, like this for each entry of first file.
My code is

```
import csv
Vlist = open("/file1.csv",'r')
Plist = open("file2.csv",'r')
VL = csv.reader(Vlist, delimiter = '\t')
PL = csv.reader(Plist, delimiter = '\t')
for row in VL:
    for col in PL:
        if row[0] == col[0]:
            print(col[1])
```

The output of this code is:

```
a
```

but I want to iterate each value of column in file1 and search for it in file2

Comment: What is the issue with your code? You have to be more specific in your question.

Comment: What is the question?  Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you correctly, you need apply `seek` for `Plist`

```
for row in VL:
    # Add next line
    Plist.seek(0)
    for col in PL:
        if row[0] == col[0]:
            print(col[1])
```